# Detecting synchronization cascades in time series

Tags: pattern-recognition

I am researching delayed synchronisation in a system of coupled oscillators. There is a one-way causal connection between the oscillators, which leads to the synchronisation events occurring in a rough sequence.

When I plot this data a very clear pattern emerges:
[image: synchronisation cascades]

I am looking for a way of identifying and fitting a line to the highlighted areas of the graph. Do you have any ideas on how to find these patterns?

Comment: you should provide more details as to the nature of the problem, the structure of data and what "lines" are preferred

Answer (score 0):

One option is:

1. Threshold at ~10 to remove the baseline values.
2. Fit a clustering algorithm to identify groups.
3. For each cluster, fit a linear regression. If the linear regression has certain a slope label cluster as a synchronization event.